# ReactNative:How to change the header for tab navigator inside a drawer navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am building a react native app with a login and profile screen.The navigation is as below:
I wanted to change the header title when I navigate to each tabs.Also, i want my drawer to be able to open from any screen.So drawer icon should always be in the profile at left.
I cant make the header none/hide in profile screen as it will hide the drawer icon as well.Any idea how to solve it?

```
const TabStack = TabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsTab
    }
  }
);

const DrawerMain = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    TabStack: {
      screen: TabStack
    }
  },
  {
    drawerOpenRoute: "DrawerOpen",
    drawerCloseRoute: "DrawerClose"
);
const Profile = StackNavigator(
  {
    DrawerMain: {
      screen: DrawerMain   
  }
},
{
    headerMode: "screen",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "white"
      },
      headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            if (navigation.state.index === 0) {
              navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen");
            } else {
              navigation.navigate("DrawerClose");
            }
          }}
        >
          <Icon name={"ios-menu"} size={20} style={{ color: "red" }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  }
);
export default (App = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
  }
}));
```

[This is how the profile should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAIiK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your navigation hierarchy to like this.

Drawer

ㄴ Stack

__ ㄴ Tab

Then, you need to pass DrawerNavigator's navigation to StackNavigator to control a drawer from a button in StackNavigator.

And use it through `screenProps`.

```
...

const Profile = StackNavigator(
  {
    TabStack: {
      screen: TabStack   
  }
},
navigationOptions: ({ screenProps }) => ({
      ...
      headerLeft: (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
              screenProps.myDrawerNavigation.navigate("DrawerOpen");
          }}
        >
          <Icon name={"ios-menu"} size={20} style={{ color: "red" }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
...


const DrawerMain = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: ({navigation}) => <Profile screenProps={{myDrawerNavigation:navigation}}/>
    }
  },
  ...
```

Comment: I tried using this procedure.But i am  getting below error when accessing drawer icon from the screen. "undefined is not an object.evaluating(navigation.screenProps.myDrawerNavigation.navigate("DrawerOpen");. I am new to react.Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: @SnehaS Oops, I'm sorry. I edited my answer to `screenProps.` from `navigation.screenProps`. and I made a working sample for you. here. https://snack.expo.io/rJIKh61Sf

Comment: But still, as I said I am not able to add a different header for different tabs in the profile. If I hide the header in the main navigator and add header in each navigation page separately it is hiding the drawer menu as well as attached